# CSS Background Color stops at last element

Tags: css

Feeling like a total n00b here. I have a short page that doesn't fill an entire page vertically. For some reason my `background-color` set on the `body` tag doesn't continue past the last element on the page.

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

What could cause this?

Comment: plunker? fiddle? bin?

Comment: Could you provide an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: probably it depends on body height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I simply add a `background-color` to the `html` element. Does the trick.

```
html { background-color: #fff;}
```

When my page footer is a different color than the page background, I usually will style the `html` element to have the same bg color, that way it appears the footer stretches to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: This did fill the background of the entire page. I've inspected the body and container tags in Firebug and can't find anything that may be causing it. So, thank you for the solution and I'll keep looking for the cause ;).

Comment: @DMX I'm glad this worked for you! This isn't really a bug, though. There's no "cause". As far as the browser is concerned, your page's `body` ends at a certain point before filling the viewport, so there is nothing left for the browser to render. By Default, the body will only scale down as far as it's content dictates. The solution is to tell the browser to apply a `background-color` to the entire `html` document, and it just so happens that the browser decides that everything seen in the viewport is part of `html`, so the background isn't limited by the content.

Comment: I certainly didn't think it was a bug, just a set of instructions I didn't fully understand. I always thought that the `body` tag filled the viewport. Guess I learned something new today!

Answer (score 5):

Tell the body element that it needs to take up at least the full browser height

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, style the `html` tag not the `body` tag

Comment: Upvote for the "style the html" part (which did fix it). Unfortunately, min-height on the body or html tag had no effect.

Comment: You might have to set the `height` of the `html` to 100% for the body to recognise it. Either way, if it worked styling the html tag then all good!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
* { 
   background-color: yellow; // or anything you want.
}
```

If you want to change the background color of the other element you'll just have to select it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz94q2ko/3/)

Comment: Setting everything to that BG color is going to require a lot of extra code to put elements back to their original values.